# Compilation error from github source

Tags: linux, git, compile, github

I am trying to install/compile [qstardict](https://github.com/a-rodin/qstardict) for my openSUSE.  Following the instruction:

Before building fetch `libqxt` submodule:

```
git submodule init && git submodule update
```

To build and install:

1. `qmake [switches]`
2. `make`
3. `make install`

But when I do `git submodule init`, the error comes:

```
fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /home)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you init a local Git repository, into which this remote is supposed to be added?

Does your local directory have a .git folder?

First delete the old .git directory : rm -rf .git

Then initialize the git repo again :  git init.